# buildout error, zc.buildout downgrade

Tags: plone, buildout

I was hoping somebody would help me with this problem. I installed a copy of my plone site to another pc for add on testing.

While I'm trying to install xmpp chat I have updated the zc.buildout to 1.6.3 which caused me some errors on buildout and upon. Checking the original installation the zc.buildout version is 1.4.4 ...

My question now is, how to get the 1.6.3 to 1.4.4.

Btw the error for now is version conflict we already have zc.buildout 1.6.3 and when I change the zc.buildout = 1.6.3 to 1.4.4 on the buildout.cfg file got some different  errors refering to zc.buildout too.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `bootstrap.py` takes a version switch to pick a specific `zc.buildout` version, is that what you are looking for? `python bootstrap.py -v 1.4.4`.

Comment: Perhaps you should share the errors you are getting.

Comment: I think what caused my problem is the accidental change of zc.buildout version on my buildout.cfg.I found out that the original version is 1.4.4,and I accidentally changed it while I'm trying to add some lines from the xmpp.chat buildout tutorials.While I run bin/buildout it stops saying "version conflict we already have zc.buildout 1.6.3." And when I do "locate zc.buildout",matches are 1.6.3 and when I do similar command on the original plone site matches are 1.4.4,so my opinion is that this may caused the errors.I'm thinking if I can get it back to 1.4.4. the buildout error might be solved.

Comment: hello @MartijnPieters here is the error messages [click here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GnFY9fYECDAHdGauf_fM9JcpHwI_kAJLzWfnuAdIRus/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: the error says "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: I don't think the version of zc.buildout is causing that error.

Comment: You have an error in your sources section.